# On $p^{\log_q n}$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, open-problem, rationality-testing

Let $p,q$ be distinct primes, $n>1$ an integer with $\log_q n $  irrational. It was, and probably still is, a conjecture that $p^{\log_q n}$ is non-integer. What progress has been made towards it?

Comment: Where did you find this conjecture?

Comment: @Marco: I wish I could remember... probably I read about it in a paper by Erdos, but too long has passed since then.

Comment: @Marco: If only I had seen your comment (much) earlier.